# Eclipse Juno Content Assist Error

Tags: java, eclipse, intellisense

I have installed Eclipse Juno Build id: 20120614-1722. java jdk version is:

$ java -version

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Jre version is:

$javac -version

```
javac 1.7.0_07
```

The problem is, whenever I want to call a method e.g. System.out.print(); I get the below error and trace log.

Error
[image: Error after typing System.]

Below is the beginning of the tracelog.

```
Exception in thread "AutoAssist Delay" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: 
Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.LinkageError: 
loader constraint violation: when resolving method                                                                   "org.eclipse.recommenders.utils.rcp.JdtUtils.
createUnresolvedType(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/TypeBinding;)
Lcom/google/common/base Optional;" 

the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) 
of the current class,
org/eclipse/recommenders/internal/completion/rcp/BaseRecommendersCompletionContext, 
and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader)
for resolved class,org/eclipse/recommenders/utils/rcp/JdtUtils
have different Class objects for the type 
pse.recommenders.utils.rcp.JdtUtils.
createUnresolvedType(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler
/lookup/TypeBinding;)Lcom/google/common/base/Optional; used in the signature)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4291)
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `metadata` directory? The release of Juno is R-4.2-201206081400

Comment: have you tried netbeans, or intellij ? I got fed up with stuff like this and swapped a while ago and don't regret it (after  10 years of a love hate relationship with eclipse)

Comment: @PaulVargas, I have not done that and how can I delete that? The release I got is Build id: 20120614-1722.

Comment: @NimChimpsky, I have not tried Netbeans or Intellij. I think eclipse has been a good IDE for me and I did not face much issues with it.

Comment: See http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html

Comment: @PaulVargas, I've tried starting eclipse with the -clean switch but I got the same error. By the way this is a clean installation.

Comment: @fanbondi these issues don't exist with the other two I mentioned.